# Can't get mouse event to trigger on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm playing around with a canvas project from school. I've played around with some triggers I found that would work for a drawing function with mouse and keyboard events, but I can't get the mouse events to trigger on the canvas.

I was looking for something that would work with mouse movement since its a drag and drop draw project where I need a mouse movement. I have tried to set a breakpoint in the `GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown` method but I can't get the trigger to happen.

**CS Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GridCanvas.MouseMove += GridCanvas_MouseMove;
        GridCanvas.MouseDown += GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        GridCanvas.MouseUp   += GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Mainwindow_ColorKeyDown);
    }
    void Mainwindow_ColorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.B:
                {
                    mySolidColorBrush.Color=Color.FromArgb(0,255,255,255);
                }
                break;
            default:
                {

                }
                break;
        }
    }
   private void GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
        _startingPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(GridCanvas);
   }

    private void GridCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!GridCanvas.IsMouseCaptured) { return; }
        Point endPoint = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(GridCanvas);
      
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
        {
            //draw line
            Line myLine = new Line();
            myLine.Stroke = mySolidColorBrush;
            myLine.X1 = _startingPoint .X;
            myLine.Y1 = _startingPoint .Y;
            myLine.X2 = endPoint .X;
            myLine.Y2 = endPoint .Y;
        }
    }

    private void GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GridCanvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private Point _startingPoint ;
    private SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give GridCanvas a transparent Background first, either in xaml, or code.